# Disable x-axis sorting in line chart

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I have the following simple data.frame:

```
x <- data.frame(x = c(1, 3, 5, 2, 4, runif(10)),
                y = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, runif(10)))
```

I want to make a plot showing both the scatter plot and connecting some of the points with a line, so I use:

```
plot_ly(data = x) %>%
  add_markers(
    x = ~x,
    y = ~y
  ) %>%
  add_lines(
    x = ~x[1:5],
    y = ~y[1:5]
  )
```

However, the resulting line graph is sorted along the x-axis, while I want the line to follow the order found in the data.frame (shown in red below).

[image]

Is there any way of doing this? I've found similar questions on SO, but they all deal with categorical values.

I could obviously use paths, but to my understanding those only exist as shapes within `layout()`. I'm hoping for something which behaves like a trace: responds to hover actions, appears (and can be hidden) in the legend, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just found a solution by using `add_paths` instead of `add_lines`.

```
plot_ly(data = x) %>%
  add_markers(
    x = ~x,
    y = ~y
  ) %>%
  add_paths(
    x = ~x[1:5],
    y = ~y[1:5]
  )
```

[image: New plot]

Hope it solves your challenge.

Comment: How had I never seen `add_paths` before?!

Comment: I found it in the help file `?add_lines`